# iOS Swipe Between Two View Controllers and Tap To a Third

Tags: ios, storyboard

I would like to do as much of this via storyboards as possible. I've looked around and have seen a lot of different approaches, but so far they don't seem to hit what I'm attempting:

Swiping left on View 1 will slide View 1 off-screen and slide View 2 on-screen from right to left.Swiping right on View 2 will perform the reverse. Additionally, swiping left on View 1 will trigger View 2 to perform some calculations to generate dynamic values. View 3 will slide up over View 1 when a button on View 1 is tapped, and slide back down when a button on View 3 is tapped.

Any suggestions or links?

Comment: You can use UIView instead of UIViewController.

Comment: You may search for **ContainerViewController**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a swipe gesture recogniser to each of View Controller 1 and View Controller 2 on the storyboard.

Within the View Controller code associated with View Controller 1 add the

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(id)sender {
    // Your code here - show View 2, do your calculations;
}
```

Similarly within the View Controller code associated with View Controller 2 add the

```
- (IBAction)swipeRight:(id)sender {
    // Your code here - show View 1;
}
```

On StoryBoard View 1 and View 3 have a button. In the method in the associated View Controller code have them show View 3 and View 1 respectively.

```
- (IBAction)buttonNamePress:(id)sender {
    // Your code here - show the appropriate View.
}
```